# Sending an email to multiple addressees as "BCC" and making sure they do not see "undisclosed recipients"

Tags: email, thunderbird, gmail

If I send an email to multiple addressees, each of them in a "BCC" field, I wanna make sure that each person does not know other people received that email.
For example when I ask around for a quote, it is just easier to send the same email to many BCCs. However today one of them replied asking: "who else in our company did you send it to?I just want to make sure we are not doing double work. "

Then I sent a few trial emails to friends (2  addressees both BCC) and some friends didn't see  "undisclosed recipients" under the field "To" while other had it. Some had "undisclosed recipients" in the computer, some only in the phone.

How can I make sure no one sees "undisclosed recipients" in the email they receive, and that they do not know there are other addressees? I am using my university edu email, and smtp.gmail.com as outgoing server. Using Thunderbird under Windows, if all this matters.

Comment: Do you have “To:” and/or “Cc:” recipients?  Or is it *just* “Bcc”?

Answer (score 6):

I suspect whether the recipient sees that message or not is based on their own mail server/client which fills it in if it sees a blank `To:` field. One way to avoid that would be to put your own email in the `To:` line. However, it might still raise questions if someone notices their own email not in the `To:` field.

Comment: is correct - I am unaware if any mechanism in the email specification that allows this behaviour. You woukd need to send out multiple emails, or find /write a mail client that does tjis or modify your MTA (mail server to do this). Modifying a Postfix MTA to do this is likely to be the most doable, but will still tequire some non-trivial scripting to create, and will change the way bcc behaves (bcc is designed to silently copy other entities in on an email to keep them in the loop without the person/people in the to and cc fields being aware.)

Comment: well it does not work that way, if people read "undisclosed recipients" then they are aware!

Comment: @Millemila: What do you mean by “it does not work that way”?